# Node.js function calls parts of code twice

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, logic

I'm learning Node and can't quite wrap my head around what is happening here.  This function is suppose to create a chat room document in MongoDB if the room name doesn't already exist.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Chat = require("../Models/Chat");


async function CreateRoom(req, res) {
    const { room, username, _id } = req.body;
    console.log(`CHAT: createRoom ${room}`);

    const chat = await Chat.findOne({ "room": room }).exec();
    console.log(`____x`)    
    if (chat) {
        console.log(`____0`)
        res.sendStatus(409); // Conflict        
    }
console.log(`____1`)
    const result = await Chat.create({
        room: room,
        message: [
            {
                text: "Room created",
                from: _id,
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log("____2")    
    if (!result) {
        console.log(`CHAT: createRoom ${room} failed`);
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    console.log("____3")
    console.log(`CHAT room created: ${room}`);
    return res.sendStatus(201);
}

module.exports = { CreateRoom };
```

The output looks like this:

```
CHAT: createRoom lobby
____x
____1
____x
____1
____2
____3
CHAT room created: lobby
____2
____3
CHAT room created: lobby
```

I'm completely baffled at how the "____x" shows up twice, as well as the other duplicates.  Can anyone enlighten me on how this is possible?  Thanks.

Comment: `CreateRoom` is called twice probably. It looks like some kind of endpoint handler, so probably the same request is sent twice

Comment: The "CHAT: createRoom lobby" is only output once, so I don't think the function would be called twice.  Plus the order of the output is confusing.  Unless I'm not understanding the console.log function

Comment: I should have mentioned this is in a controller file using express and routing.  Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Post the file that has your routes defined. You are probably handling the route twice somehow.

Comment: Note also that after you do `res.sendStatus()` or `res.send()`, you need to `return` from your function so that the code that comes after it is NOT executed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a second call happening.  The logging was hidden until I added some more.

```
************************************
REQUEST: OPTIONS /chat/create
************************************
CORS allowed  http://localhost:3000


************************************
REQUEST: OPTIONS /chat/create
************************************
CORS allowed  http://localhost:3000


************************************
REQUEST: POST /chat/create
************************************
CORS allowed  http://localhost:3000
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1pa2UiLCJyb2xlcyI6IlVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTgwMTIzMDcsImV4cCI6MTY5ODAxMzIwN30.i_lB5PFuKSqziXUbE8bu7oKFvKeFcJp70XcQufyRNoA
decoded: mike
CHAT: createRoom {lobby, mike,653579bf19d6b0f0082ad608


************************************
REQUEST: POST /chat/create
************************************
CORS allowed  http://localhost:3000
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1pa2UiLCJyb2xlcyI6IlVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTgwMTIzMDcsImV4cCI6MTY5ODAxMzIwN30.i_lB5PFuKSqziXUbE8bu7oKFvKeFcJp70XcQufyRNoA
decoded: mike
CHAT: createRoom {lobby, mike,653579bf19d6b0f0082ad608
____x
____0
____x
____0
```

The "CHAT: createRoom" log entry appears in the first post, then a second post happens and the rest of the logging appears to look like it is from the second post.

I still have some trouble thinking non-linearly.